# Show full build output in CLion

Tags: ubuntu, ide

I'm happily using CLion for some time now but what really annoys me is that I don't get the full build output messages.
This really gets annoying if e.g. I forget to declare an external library to link my project to and the build fails because of undefined references.
Instead of showing me these `undefined reference...` messages it just says `Build failed`. In order to get the cause for the failure I have to manually compile the project in order to get the full build messages.

I would like to know if there is any option to enable verbose build output?
I'm using CLion 2016.1.1 on Ubuntu 15.10 using the bundled CMake 3.5.1 and  the bundled GDB 7.8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### I would like to know if there is any option to enable verbose build output?

> Any suggestions to display build commands directly in Clion terminal?
>
> We can set make verbosity in `CMakeLists.txt` by adding `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)`.
>
> There is no GUI option for that at the moment.

[Source via archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20151225125414/http://sofd.developer-works.com/article/19070767/Display+build+command+in+Clion+terminal)

Comment: Hmm... the result of this setting isn't stable in CLion. Sometimes it shows linker errors, sometimes it only shows '/usr/bin/ld: ' but nothing further. but I think it should do what I want